# jQuery sort function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

Based on the user location and a store location I try to figure out what the distance is between this two. This is working, but what I want is an array with all the values and sort on the distance between the two points.

I have my `add_stores_to_array` function, wich add all stores to the array `stores` when it is looping through the JSON file.

```
add_stores_to_array = function(position) {
    var user_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var user_longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $.getJSON('/stores').done(function(data) {

        $.each(data.features, function(i, item) {
            var store_latitude = item.geometry.coordinates[1];
            var store_longitude = item.geometry.coordinates[0];

            var user = new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);
            var store = new google.maps.LatLng(store_latitude, store_longitude);

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            var request = {
                origin:user,
                destination:store,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    var response = Math.ceil(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);

                    // add distance and store id to the array stores
                    stores.push({distance: response, id: item.properties.Nid});
                }
            });
        });

        // call the sort function
        sort_stores(stores);

        console.log(stores);

    });
};
```

After the `$.each` I call the sort function. But after logging it to the console, it is still not sorted.

My `sort_stores` function:

```
sort_stores = function(stores){
    stores.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.distance - b.distance;
    });
};
```

First I thought it wasn't working because the `$.each` was still running, but after adding this code, it still doesn't working:

```
if (i == Object.keys(data.features).pop()) {
    sort_stores(stores);
}
```

So, I tried something different. I call the `sort_stores(stores)` function in the `$.each`.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var response = Math.ceil(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);

        stores.push({distance: response, id: item.properties.Nid});
        sort_stores(stores);
    }
});
```

And it works.. the array is sorted based on the value distance in the array. But now he sorts the array after each added store.. not really effective.

Is there a proper way to call the `sort_stores(stores)` function one time, and sort it when all stores are added to the array?

**EDIT:**

If I place an `alert()` before the `sort_stores(stores)` it is working..

```
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    var response = Math.ceil(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);

                    stores.push({distance: response, id: item.properties.Nid});
                }
            });
        });

        alert('Call the sort_stores(stores) function after the $.each, with an alert.. it is working?');
        sort_stores(stores);
    });
};
```

**Edit 2:**

Normally I call the function `add_stores_to_array` from here?

```
get_user_location = function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(add_stores_to_array);
    }
};
```

Comment: try `a.distance > b.distance ? 1 : a.distance < b.distance ? -1 : 0`

Comment: Hm, it looks like the function `stores.sort(function(a, b)` is not even running if I place it after the `$.each`? If I place an `alert()` inside the `stores.sort(function(a, b)` nothings happend?

Comment: did you check the console for errors? edit: nothing's wrong with your sort function. once you get the function working, it will work accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but there are no erros.. please see my edit in my first post.

Comment: well it's in the `$.getJSON('/stores').done(function(data) { }` block and supposed to work after `$.each()`. there should be an error. check with chrome if you didn't do so. edit: ok, looks like a race condition due to an async call.

Comment: No seriously, there are no errors in the console. Not in IE, Firefox or Google Chrome. Oh, a race?

Comment: it's because `directionsService.route` is an async call. your code keeps on running even if the call is not yet completed. so sort is not applied to all elements becuase the array is not yet filled out with all the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127882/discussion-between-alter-ego-and-ozgur-bar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your sort function. The problem is that `directionsService.route` is asynchronous call and the rest of the code will run even when all the calls are not completed yet.

You can use [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Here is the new `add_stores_to_array()` function

```
add_stores_to_array = function(position) {
    var promises = []; //ADDED promise array
    var user_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var user_longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $.getJSON('/stores').done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.features, function(i, item) {
            var store_latitude = item.geometry.coordinates[1];
            var store_longitude = item.geometry.coordinates[0];

            var user = new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);
            var store = new google.maps.LatLng(store_latitude, store_longitude);

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            var request = {
                origin:user,
                destination:store,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            var dfd = directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    var response = Math.ceil(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);

                    // add distance and store id to the array stores
                    stores.push({distance: response, id: item.properties.Nid});
                }
            });

            promises.push(dfd); //ADDED store each object in array
        });

        //Now you can do the following without having any async issue.
        $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { 
           /* sort & do stuff here */ 
           sort_stores(stores);
           console.log(stores);
        });
    });
};
```

**EDIT**

Here is another approach. Since you need to wait until all responses are returned, you can customize your sort function to check for the response count. If it's equal to total (which means all calls have finished successfully) then  sort the array.

```
sort_stores = function(stores, responseCount, totalCount ) {
    if (responseCount == totalCount) {
        stores.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.distance - b.distance;
        });
    }
};
```

Then change the `add_stores_to_array` function as follows.

```
add_stores_to_array = function(position) {
    var user_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var user_longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $.getJSON('/stores').done(function(data) {
        var totalCount = data.features.length; //ADDED Get total count
        var responseCount = 0; //ADDED
        $.each(data.features, function(i, item) {
            var store_latitude = item.geometry.coordinates[1];
            var store_longitude = item.geometry.coordinates[0];

            var user = new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);
            var store = new google.maps.LatLng(store_latitude, store_longitude);

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            var request = {
                origin:user,
                destination:store,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    var response = Math.ceil(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);

                    // add distance and store id to the array stores
                    stores.push({distance: response, id: item.properties.Nid});
                    responseCount++; //ADDED
                    sort_stores(stores, responseCount, totalCount); //ADDED Call sort function here
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I can call the `add_stores_to_array().done(function() {` anywhere, because of the `.done()`, right?

Comment: yes but I need to change the code a little bit, it does not seem to work.

Comment: `$.when.apply(null, add_stores_to_array()).done(function() { ` from where I should call this function? See my fist post, edit 2 please.

Comment: see the updated answer please. no need to change the function call. i've put the code in `add_stores_to_array` function.

Comment: Still no luck here, it's not sorting when I call the function in `$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { `.

Comment: ok can you add `console.log("directionsService.route request sent");` before `promises.push(dfd);`. and add `console.log("all done");` in `$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { });`? if you are seeing `directionsService.route request sent` after `all done` in console, it means not working properly. normally `all done` should be the last message in console.

Comment: then it's working. `$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { sort_stores(stores); });` should get the job done?

Comment: No, it is not working when I use the `sort` function (img: https://static.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/1611/196964/lmIUtJeA.jpg).

Comment: ok what happens when you also put `console.log("sorting started")` in the beginning of `sort_stores` and `console.log("sorting finished")` at the end? are those still the last messages  in console window?

Comment: In the `stores.sort(function(a, b){` or outside?

Comment: in the function. `sort_stores = function(stores){ console.log("sorting"); ..... console.log("finished"); }`

Comment: any console error? are you doing it this way? `$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { sort_stores(stores); });` because you said you can see the `all done` message in the console. we are simply replacing `console.log` with `sort_stores(stores);` it should also work...

Comment: Ah now it shows sorting started, after that sorting finished. The function is running but he is not sorting the array.. if I place an `alert()` before the `sort_stores(stores)` function, the sorting works..

Comment: you don't need the alert anymore. `when` took care of the async problem (we checked the console). the code in when block will not run until all the async calls are finished. I will update the answer to avoid confusion. we are missing something else here..

Comment: Hmm, but it is weird, if I set a `timeout` on the function of x seconds it works to. It seems like, he is still sorting without data?

Comment: seems so.. but you said `all done` was the last message in console. can you verify that? are you sure there is no "directionsService.route request sent" message after that?

Comment: ok can you also add `console.log("store pushed")` after `stores.push({distance: response, id: item.properties.Nid});`? is `all done` still the last message?

Comment: I have updated the answer. can you try the second approach?

Comment: great! you're welcome. wish the deferred object approach worked though:]